# How many ways to print our array of integer array?

Tags: c, arrays

I can declare array of integer array like this:

```
int dataA[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
```

and print the array out respectively like this two ways：

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int dataA[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < 3; i++) {
        int j = 0;
        for (; j < 3; j++)
            printf("%i,", dataA[i][j]);
        printf(";");
    }

    puts("");

    int dataB[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    int *p = (int *) dataB;
    int m = 0;
    for (; m < 3; m++) {
        int n = 0;
        for (; n < 3; n++)
            printf("%i,", *p + ((m * 3) + n));
        printf(";");
    }

return 0;
}
```

How about if I declare this way(is this declaration right?), how to print out them in this way?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    puts("");

    int *dataC[3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    /*
     * How to print out the array in this situation?
     */

    puts("");

    int x[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int y[] = { 4, 5, 6 };
    int z[] = { 7, 8, 9 };
    int *dataD[3] = { &x, &y, &z };
    /*
     * How to print out the array in this situation?
     */

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dataC` cannot be initialised this way. The elements of `dataC` is of type `int *`, while you are initialising them with `int []`.

As commented by @WhozCraig, it will be a valid initialisation if you did:

```
int *dataC[3] = {(int []){1, 2, 3}, (int []){4, 5, 6}, (int []){7, 8, 9}};
```

And you can output the array using the same method you used for `dataA`.

`dataD` cannot be initialised this way either. The elements of `dataD` is of type `int *`. `x`, `y` and `z` can be converted to type `int *`, but your use of the `&` operator is incorrect - `&x` here is of type `int **`, not `int *`.

It will be a valid initialisation if you did:

```
int *dataD[3] = { x, y, z };
```

If this is the case, you can simply output this array using the same method you used for `dataA`.

Comment: Is there a way like cast can make  int *dataC[3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } }; valid?

Comment: @LeeWilliam *compound literal* :  `int *dataC[3] = {(int[]){ 1, 2, 3 }, (int[]){ 4, 5, 6 }, (int[]){ 7, 8, 9 } };` [See it live](http://ideone.com/E47X2g).

Comment: @WhozCraig That's exactly what I want to know, thanks.